# dropdown javascript for bulma framework

Tags: javascript, jquery, bulma

i have the following problem, i am trying to use two dropdowns using javascript and bulma framework

but the problem is that only one dropdown is displayed when I click on it but if I click on the second one it doesn't open.

```
<div class="dropdown">
  <div class="dropdown-trigger">
    <button class="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-controls="dropdown-menu">
      <span>Dropdown button</span>
      <span class="icon is-small">
        <i class="fas fa-angle-down" aria-hidden="true"></i>
      </span>
    </button>
  </div>
  <div class="dropdown-menu" id="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
    <div class="dropdown-content">
      <a href="#" class="dropdown-item">
        Dropdown item
      </a>
      <a class="dropdown-item">
        Other dropdown item
      </a>
      <a href="#" class="dropdown-item is-active">
        Active dropdown item
      </a>
      <a href="#" class="dropdown-item">
        Other dropdown item
      </a>
      <hr class="dropdown-divider">
      <a href="#" class="dropdown-item">
        With a divider
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="dropdown">
  <div class="dropdown-trigger">
    <button class="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-controls="dropdown-menu">
      <span>Dropdown button</span>
      <span class="icon is-small">
        <i class="fas fa-angle-down" aria-hidden="true"></i>
      </span>
    </button>
  </div>
  <div class="dropdown-menu" id="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
    <div class="dropdown-content">
      <a href="#" class="dropdown-item">
        Dropdown item
      </a>
      <a class="dropdown-item">
        Other dropdown item
      </a>
      <a href="#" class="dropdown-item is-active">
        Active dropdown item
      </a>
      <a href="#" class="dropdown-item">
        Other dropdown item
      </a>
      <hr class="dropdown-divider">
      <a href="#" class="dropdown-item">
        With a divider
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

JavaScript Code:

```
var dropdown = document.querySelector('.dropdown');
dropdown.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
  event.stopPropagation();
  dropdown.classList.toggle('is-active');
});
```

I have the respective libraries loaded both bulma and jquery, but I still can't get both dropdowns to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are on the right track, but you're using `.querySelector()` incorrectly. See the [docs](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_document_queryselector.asp):

> The querySelector() method returns the **first** element that matches a specified CSS selector(s) in the document

Emphasis mine.

The solution is to use `.querySelectorAll()`. This will return an array of **all** the dropdowns. You can then iterate through them and attach an eventlistener to them.

```
document.querySelectorAll('.dropdown').forEach(item => {
    item.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
        event.stopPropagation();
        item.classList.toggle('is-active');
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

@Klaassiek's answer works here, but in my case the dropdown content had interactive elements and if you clicked any of them the entire dropdown would toggle back off.  This minor change makes it so that the dropdown stays visible unless the trigger element itself is clicked again:

```
document.querySelectorAll('.dropdown-trigger').forEach(item => {
    item.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
        event.stopPropagation();
        item.parentNode.classList.toggle('is-active');
    });
});
```